# Change values from other scripts without having the target script attached to an GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

iam pretty new in C# and Unity and facing currently following issue in my game project.
Ive a class to instantiate for various shops each shop makes a different profit has a different name and coasts different power recourses. So my idea is to have a class to make those shops and on constructor call e.g shop creation it should change variables of another script where the balance, power, and so on is calculated here the example code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Shops
{
    public int shopID;
    public string shopName;
    public float shopPower;
    public double shopCoast;
    public string shopType;
    public double shopProfit;

    public Shops(int id, string name, float power, double coast, string type, double profit)
    {
        this.shopID = id;
        this.shopName = name;
        this.shopPower = power;
        this.shopCoast = coast;
        this.shopType = type;
        this.shopProfit = profit;

        Debug.Log("Shop created");

        addProfit(profit);
        subPower(power);
        subCoast(coast);
        
    }

    

    public void addProfit(double profit)
    {
        
    }



    public void subPower(float power)
    {

    }

    public void subCoast(double coast)
    {

    }




}



using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Calculations : MonoBehaviour
{
    public double money;
    public float power;
    public double profitPerHour, coastPerHour, totalPerHour;




    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Is it correct or lets say common the way ive written it and that the constructor calls a few methods on call? And how can i accsess the variable double money from the Calculations : Monobeheivor script without the script being attached to a game object? Is there a way without attaching it to a gameobject or not? My idea is that the calculation script does all the calculations needed and iam just grabing the values for my UI from this script. Or wont the update() and start function work?

**And one more Question**
How can i store all created classobjects in a list or array so that i can print it later in a table where its sorted for example from lowest to highest profit. What is better to use an array or a list?

I hope i made my question clear and thank you in advance.

Comment: 1) It is not common or a good idea to have constructors call methods.  The reason is that constructors should be lightweight, such that they mostly just assign values to some fields and properties.  And you don't want a constructor to call any method that might throw an exception due to invalid arguments or null references or anything.  Don't allow situations where a constructor might throw an exception.  2) `MonoBehaviour`s *have* to be attached to game objects.  If it won't be attached to a game object, it should not be a `MonoBehaviour`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Okay would you then do it like this:
Shop shop1 = new Shop(.....);
and then run the methods created in the Shop class like this
shop1.addProfit(...);
?
Bet then ive to call a lot of methods after every shop creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Ben Rubin said in his comment, it is not a good idea to do another things than initialization of variables in the constructor. But you could do a method eg. `Init()` which will calls the methods on other classes.

If you have a calculation instance for each shop, then maybe you should merge the 2 classes in only one.

However, if your calculation is global for all the shops, you could make it singleton, without having to make it a `MonoBehaviour`. And inside you register your shops in a list where you can then access later inside the Calculations class.

```cs
public class Shop
{
    ...

    public Shop(...)
    {
        // initialize only your variables
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        Calculations.Instance.RegisterShop(this, true);
        // Do your calls to other classes here
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        Calculations.Instance.RegisterShop(this, false);
    }

    ...
}
```

```cs
public class Calculations
{
    private static Calculations m_instance = null;
    public static Calculations Instance { // singleton
        get {
            if(m_instance == null)
                m_instance = new Calculations();
            return m_instance;
        }
    }

    private List<Shop> shopList = new List<Shop>();

    public RegisterShop(Shop shop, bool register)
    {
         bool isRegistered = shopList.Contains(shop);
         if(register && !isRegistered)
             shopList.Add(shop);
         else if(!register && isRegistered)
             shopList.Remove(shop);
    }

    ...
}
```

And for exemple in a script `ShopSeller`, attached to a GameObject in your scene (I don't know if you do something like that)

```cs
public class ShopSeller : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Shop shop = null;

    public void Start()
    {
        shop = new Shop(...);
        shop.Init();
    }

    public void OnDestroy()
    {
        shop?.Clear();
    }

    ...
}
```

**Note** that singleton needs to be used wisely, it is not the answer for all difficulties you encounter. It is the only way I can think of for you to not make a MonoBehaviour and attach it to a GameObject to use it.

For your bonus question, you could refer to [this chart](https://i0.wp.com/adrinael.net/containerchoice.png) if you want to choose an appropriate container for what you want to do.

It uses the C++ container types, but it remain the same with some translations to C# :

- vector = List
- list = LinkedList
- map = Dictionary
- set = HashSet
- deque = no equivalent in C#

The only things it lacks is the basic array, it is useful when you know exactly the length, and you know it will never grow or shrink during runtime.